# Add mean, 1st, and 3rd quartile to the legend of box plot combined with point plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a list of data and I am trying to plot a `geom_boxplot` for the rows that have `Sample` in the column `Names` and `geom_point` for the rows that have `Baseline` and `AASHTO` in the column `Names`. Below is an example of the original data. the data is stored in a list of dataframes `Plot`. I `melt` the list `plot` in order to plot the data into a series of plots using `ggplot2`. The row names are changed to a column `Names`.

```
> print(92-9)

         Ext_Multi.lane       Ext_Single.lane         Int_Multi.lane         Int_Single.lane
Baseline    0.6032482            0.4538187               0.5231752              0.3322632
Sample1     0.6149284            0.4642462               0.5081119              0.3216861
Sample2     0.6001208            0.4533191               0.5475499              0.3476186
Sample3     0.6046788            0.4554548               0.5202980              0.3325371
Sample4     0.5977068            0.4486637               0.4949881              0.3144831
Sample5     0.6262543            0.4699707               0.5162286              0.3255193
Sample6     0.6215877            0.4660442               0.5074719              0.3237629
Sample7     0.5985551            0.4512014               0.5410862              0.3450809
Sample8     0.5806672            0.4369405               0.5287744              0.3352956
Sample9     0.5997632            0.4516018               0.5185527              0.3279376
Sample10    0.5723757            0.4347169               0.5530330              0.3531976
AASHTO      0.7520000            NA                      0.6620000              0.4260000
Mean        0.6016638            0.4532159               0.5236095              0.332711
```

The code I use is:

```
Plot <- map2(Shear_melt, Moment_melt, ~ full_join(.x, .y) %>%
        mutate(Names = str_remove(Names, "\\d+$")))

for (m in 1:length(Plot)) {
  plot.Moment <- ggplot(data = subset(Plot[[m]], Names = "Sample"), aes(x = Type, y = Moment)) + 
    geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
    stat_summary(fun = mean, geom="point", shape=23, size=3) + 
    stat_boxplot(geom='errorbar', linetype=1, width=0.5) + 
    geom_point(data = subset(Plot[[m]], Names != "Sample"), aes(colour = Names)) +
    scale_color_manual(values=c("red","green4","black")) + 
    theme(axis.title.x=element_blank()) +
    theme(axis.title.y=element_blank()) +
    labs(title = "Moment Live Load Distribution Factors",
         color =  paste('UG', names(Plot)[m])) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
          legend.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
  print(plot.Moment)
}
```

But I can only get the legend for `geom_point` to show on the plots. I tried `geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA)` but that messes up the plot. How to I add the labels for mean and quartile to show in thee legend for the `geom_boxplot`?
[image]

Comment: I'm a bit unsure what you are asking for: it seems there are multiple questions here.  As to why you only have one legend, it's because you only have specified one aesthetic `aes(colour = ...)`.  If you need to add another legend, you need another aesthetic (e.g. linestyle or fill...).  If you want to add a key to the legend, you can just make the `aes(...)` call again (e.g. two `geom_point()` calls from two separate dataframes, both applying `aes(colour=...)`.  For labeling means and quantiles, what are you looking to do there?

Comment: @chemdork123 I have the current legend showing the points. I want to add legend items indicating the mean and quantiles of the boxplot.

Comment: You want the numbers to display right on the plot?  Apologies, but it is still not quite clear to me.  Can you draw and post (even photoshop your plot you post is fine) to indicate what you are looking to see?

Comment: @chemdork123 Sorry for the confusion. As you see there are currently 2 items in the legend one shows AASHTO points and one shows Baseline points. I want to add a diamond for the mean and the 1st quartile box and 3rd quartile bars to the legend. currently, only the legend for point plot is showing.

Comment: Gotcha.  Let I think I can help, but can't fit into a comment.  Will post an answer with some graphics to show you what you can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you currently have a legend showing AASHTO and Baseline, and you were looking to also show **in a legend** the points that you are also adding to the plot (in your case, it's the diamond for the mean as one of the other things you want to add in the legend).

Some general points first: `ggplot` creates legends for `aes(...)` calls, and it's not really easy (maybe it's possible) to combine different `aes(...)` *type* calls into one legend.  So, for example, if you have calls to `aes(color=...)` and `aes(shape=...)`, you're going to have the creation of two separate legends unless you add some fancy coding.

So the general idea for your case is to contain your `stat_summary(...)` call to include "shape" within an `aes(...)`.  Here's a demo dataset to illustrate the point:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:100, y=rnorm(100, 0.5), z=rnorm(100, 0.6, 2))
df <- df %>% gather(myThings, myValues, -x)
ggplot(df, aes(x, myValues)) + geom_point(aes(color=myThings)) +
    geom_point(data=data.frame(x=50,myValues=2), shape=23, size=3)
```

[image]

To get that diamond shape added to appear in the legend, you need to make shape appear in `aes(...)`.  The label in the legend is the label for `shape` in `aes()`.  So that means if we want to call it "Mean" in the legend, we use this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, myValues)) + geom_point(aes(color=myThings)) + 
    geom_point(data=data.frame(x=50,myValues=2), aes(shape='Mean'))
```

[image]

You still want it to be a diamond though.  So you'd think we could just add `shape=23` in there too... but no.  This code below just gives you back the original plot.  Basically, the second `shape=23` call just overrides the `aes(..)` specification:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, myValues)) + geom_point(aes(color=myThings)) + 
    geom_point(data=data.frame(x=50,myValues=2), aes(shape='Mean'), shape=23, size=3)
```

If you want to specify the actual value that `aes()` assigns to "Mean", you need to specify that with `scale_shape_manual`.  Something like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, myValues)) + geom_point(aes(color=myThings)) + 
    geom_point(data=data.frame(x=50,myValues=2), aes(shape='Mean'), size=3) + 
    scale_shape_manual(values=23)
```

[image]

That should help you add the diamond for "Mean".  As for your other points, just specify with aesthetic in a similar way and it will appear as a legend.  You can use `labs(shape=...)` to specify the title of the legend to something other than "shape".

Comment: Thank you but I wanted to incorporate that into my boxplot. I also what to show the 1st and 3rd quartiles

Comment: The 1st and 3rd quartiles are indicated by the "top" and "bottom" of the boxes on the boxplot.  Are you looking to label them with values for text?  For those values, you can get them through using the [`quantile()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/quantile) function, and adjusting the `probs=` argument.